# PT_CONTINUE returns 'Operation not supported' on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, jailbreak, ptrace

I want writer a small debugger using ptrace on iOS jailbreaking.

Now i could attach the other process successfully,but then 'PTRACE(PT_CONTINUE, m_tid, (caddr_t)1, data)' always returns 'Operation not supported', the errno number is 45.

I just could not use PT_CONTINUE to resume the process on iOS? Is there an equivalent method to resume the process after attaching to it?

Comment: in this blogpost you can find instructions and code on how to build gdb (a version for iOS). Check out that source code, maybe it will contain an answer to your question: http://reverse.put.as/2012/04/16/how-to-compile-gdb-for-ios/